# render content in ezpublish 5 via ez_content:viewLocation without configuration or matching rules

Tags: ezpublish

Using ezpublish 2014.11 I'd like to render a location using that :

```
{{ render( controller("ez_content:viewLocation", { "locationId": location.id, "viewType":"myview" } )) }}
```

With the same template for every content.

In other words, I don't want to define matching rules in `ezpublish.yml` like that :

```
myview:
    myview:
        template: AirplAirplEzBundle::myview.html.twig
        match:
            Identifier\ContentType: [my_type]
```

And if possible I don't want any configuration at all.

Is there some kind of default template view location where I can put my twig template so they can be reached by `ez_content:viewLocation` based on viewType only ?

If not, is there any way to have a template configuration without matching rules ?

Answer (score 1):

You will need the matching configuration if you wish to use `ez_content:viewLocation`, but you can leave the `match` part empty which makes sure the rule will always apply:

```
myview:
    myview:
        template: AirplAirplEzBundle::myview.html.twig
        match: ~
```

Make sure, though, that this rule is the last one in the list for the `myview` view type, since the first rule that matches top-down applies.

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite "ez_content:viewLocation" to map to another service.

Basically you could overwrite the class-paramter for the ez_content-service and extend the old class by you own new class.
In you new class you would only need to define the method "viewLocation" and implement whatever mapping you may require.

A cleaner way would be to add all class-identifiers to the one matcher.
This way you have more controll if you want to fetch another template some day.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I added all class-identifiers to the matcher, but that's not very convenient because I now have several long identical classes lists in ezpublish.yml. Creating my own viewLocation looks like a better solution but I was wondering if there is a "native" solution for that like it used to be in eZ Publish 4